# Is there a way to tell what Material Card is needed for a Persona?

Tags: persona-2-innocent-sin

I got enough cards to create Iris but when I try to create her Igor says I don't have the requisite material card. The only material card I know about is one in Mu called "Styx" which isn't used for Iris.

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell what material card is needed for a Persona.

Comment: You have tags for *two* games here. Which is it?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie forgot to delete the first one when i found out that there was a tag for Eternal Punishment so i created a new tag using the same structure but for Innocent Sin, fixed

Comment: I thought the game didn't show personae you didn't have material cards for.

Comment: @Memor-X Ah, ok. FYI, the [[tag:persona-2-ep]] tag uses that format only because [persona-2-eternal-punishment] is over the 25-character tag length limit. [[tag:persona-2-innocent-sin]] fits though, so I made a new tag with the longer name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-game way to deduce which persona requires which card, but you can check [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/257543-persona-2-innocent-sin/faqs/54826) - it explains which material cards are necessary to summon which personae and where they can be found. In Iris' case, the card requires is Rainbow/Seven Color Light found in an item box in Aoba park.